# has won her ... on Saturday

Tags: tenses

If the following extract of a news story was published **on Saturday**, is it okay to use the present tenses and expressions like "on Saturday" rather than simply "today"?

> American teenager Isabeau Levito **has won** her first senior major international figure staking competition, claiming the Grand Prix de France title **on Saturday** ...

...

Grand Prix de France is the third of the six Grands Prix of the season. **On Saturday**, fellow American teenager Ilia Malinin **competes** in the men’s Free Skate.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2023/11/04/sport/isabeau-levito-grand-prix-de-france-spt-intl/index.html

Answer (score 1):

***It’s not okay to say today***

It has more significance to add a date to an event rather than stating “today”. Although stating “today” wouldn’t be  incorrect, ultimately it would lose context and raise confusion through time.

For example, the article was posted on Saturday but today is Monday. If I read that on Monday and the article said today, I would assume the article happened “today” and that would be any day the reader observes it. Thus creating our flaw.

Comment: The issue is the incompatibility between an expression indicating a past time and the present perfect. For example, you wouldn't say, "He has seen the movie this Tuesday."